Installing gazebo classic on ubuntu 24.04
Has anyone successfully installed Gazebo Classic on Ubuntu 24.04 (noble)? The install instructions here don't work. I know classic is EOL, but it would still be nice if it ran on noble.

This announcement appears to answer my question. ROS2 Iron / Ubuntu 22.04 will be the last release supporting gazebo classic.
https://community.gazebosim.org/t/gazebo-classic-end-of-life/2563
